# ValueError("Denominator polynomial must be rank-1 array.")

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've got the following code in [lti transient response analysis using Python(numpy, scipy, matplotlib)](http://ofan666.blogspot.in/2011/04/lti-transient-response-analysis-using.html). I am new in python. I have a transfer matrix which I have to plot.

I came across [mathwork: tf](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/control/ref/tf.html). I am trying as follows:

```
from numpy import min, max
from scipy import linspace
from scipy.signal import lti, step, impulse

num00 = [0.0]
den00 = [0.0]

num01 = [-2383.3]
den01 = [1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852]

num10 = [1.0]
den10 = [1.0]

num11 = [31.9361,0,111320.0]
den11 = [1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852]

num = [[num00,num01],[num10,num11]]
den = [[den00,den01],[den10,den11]]

tf = lti(num,den)

t = 0    
s = 0

# get t = time, s = unit-step response
t , s = step(tf)

t , s = step(tf, T = linspace(min(t), t[-1], 1000))

t , i = impulse(tf, T = linspace(min(t), t[-1], 1000))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(t, s, t, i)

plt.title('Transient-Response Analysis')
plt.xlabel('Time(sec)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.hlines(1, min(t), max(t), colors='r')
plt.hlines(0, min(t), max(t))
plt.xlim(xmax=max(t))
plt.legend(('Unit-Step Response', 'Unit-Impulse Response'), loc=0)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I am getting following error:

```
>>> tf = lti(num,den)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\ltisys.py", line 236, in __init__self.__dict__['num'], self.__dict__['den'] = normalize(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\filter_design.py", line 276, in normalize raise ValueError("Denominator polynomial must be rank-1 array.") ValueError: Denominator polynomial must be rank-1 array.
```

Comment: As the response to your comment on the linked blog says, you need a `numpy.array`, not a list. Have you gone through the numpy tutorial?

Comment: `num00 = np.array(0.0)
den00 = np.array(0.0)

num01 = np.array(-2383.3)
den01 = np.array([1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852])

num10 = np.array([1.0])
den10 = np.array([1.0]) 

num11 = np.array([31.9361,0,111320.0])
den11 = np.array([1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852])

num0010 = np.array([num00,num10])
num0011 = np.array([num01,num11])                   ` From here its list only. Seems variables can't be changed to array.

Comment: Now I did as follows : `num = np.array([[[0.0], [1.0]],[[-2383.3                         ],[31.9361,0,111320.0              ]]])
den = np.array([[[0.0], [1.0]],[[1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852],[1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852]]])
tf = lti(num,den)
` still its the same. :|

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that the num/den you are passing is not a well formed matrix.  In your code you have:

```
num01 = [-2383.3]
den01 = [1.0,160.3460,-1962.0,-314598.852]
```

This will not work very well because as far as numpy is concerned you're trying to create a matrix, I realize it's only one component of the transfer function matrix, with only 1 element in the numerator and four in the denominator.  So you would need something like:

```
num01 = [  0,       0,      0,-2383.3]
```

Either that or you meant to have an extremely high order numerator.  When I try to step that I get:
[image: Step]
Which is probably not what you expect.  I would also recommend looking into the [python-control](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/python-control/index.php?title=Main_Page) package.  Of course you'll need to get all the prerequists for that package like the [SLICOT python package](https://github.com/henjo/slicot).  I do believe that it will ultimately serve you well.

Comment: I tried as, as u mentioned. Same. I am trying from ss(a,b,c,d). Now m stuck with ImportError: No module named slycot. my system is MIMO.